# Copy low-order bytes of an integer whilst preserving endianness

Tags: c, endianness

I need to write a function that copies the specified number of low-order bytes of a given integer into an address in memory, whilst preserving their order.

```
void lo_bytes(uint8_t *dest, uint8_t no_bytes, uint32_t val)
```

I expect the usage to look like this:

```
uint8 dest[3];
lo_bytes(dest, 3, 0x44332211);
// Big-endian:    dest = 33 22 11
// Little-endian: dest = 11 22 33
```

I've tried to implement the function using bit-shifts, `memcpy`, and iterating over each byte of `val` with a for-loop, but all of my attempts failed to work on either one or the other endianness.

Is it possible to do this in a platform-independent way, or do I need to use `#ifdef`s and have a separate piece of code for each endianness?

Comment: Well, you can always test the endianness of the system in run-time by aliasing some known integer as `char*` and reading the first byte.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What would you use this function for?

Comment: Have you tried casting creating a pointer to val (`uint32_t *p32 = &val;`), casting it to a `uint8_t` pointer (`uint8_t *p8 = p32`), and then using the new pointer like an array (`p8[0]`, `p8[1]` etc.)?

Comment: Note that for types larger than two bytes, there are more than two endiannesses.  Only two are in common use right now, but others have been used in publicly available general purpose computers in the past.

Comment: @JohnBollinger and you think that anyone will use them?

Comment: @P__J__, supposedly, [one of the middle-endian formats *is* used on ARM under some circumstances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian).  In any case, I try to be careful to avoid predicting what people will do, or at least to avoid writing code that will break in the event that my predictions are incorrect.

Comment: @JohnBollinger not `used in some circumstances` only was used (And probably it was a design bug) in prehistoric FPA units

Comment: It's *possible* to do this arithmetically, but I've never managed to get a compiler to generate halfway-decent code without `#ifdef`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tried to implement the function using bit-shifts, `memcpy`, and
>   iterating over each byte of `val` with a for-loop, but all of my
>   attempts failed to work on either one or the other endianness.

All arithmetic, including bitwise arithmetic, is defined in terms of the *values* of the operands, not their representations.  This cannot be sufficient for you because you want to obtain a result that differs depending on details of the representation style for type `uint32_t`.

You can operate on object representations via various approaches, but you still need to know which bytes to operate upon.  That calls for some form of detection.  If big-endian and little-endian are the only byte orders you're concerned with supporting, then I favor an approach similar to that given in @P__J__'s answer:

```
void lo_bytes(uint8_t *dest, uint8_t no_bytes, uint32_t val) {
    static const union { uint32_t i; uint8_t a[4] } ubytes = { 1 };

    memcpy(dest, &val + (1 - ubytes.a[0]) * (4 - no_bytes), no_bytes);
}
```

The expression `(1 - ubytes.a[0])` evaluates to 1 if the representation of `uint32_t` is big endian, in which case the high-order bytes occur at the beginning of the representation of `val`.  In that case, we want to skip the first `4 - no_bytes` of the representation and copy the rest.  If `uint32_t` has a little-endian representation, on the other hand, `(1 - ubytes.a[0])` will evaluate to 0, with the result that the `memcpy` starts at the beginning of the representation.  In every case, whichever bytes are copied from the representation of `val`, their order is maintained.  That's what `memcpy()` does.

Answer (score 2):

```
int detect_endianess(void)  //1 if little endian 0 if big endianes
{
    union
    {
        uint16_t u16;
        uint8_t u8[2];
    }val = {.u16 = 0x1122};

    return val.u8[0] == 0x22;
}

void lo_bytes(void *dest, uint8_t no_bytes, uint32_t val)
{
    if(detect_endianess())
    {
        memcpy(dest, &val, no_bytes);
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(dest, (uint8_t *)(&val) + sizeof(val) - no_bytes, no_bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: _detect_endianess_ can have a smaller definition : `int detect_endianess(void) { int v = 1; return *((char *) &v); }`

Comment: Pointer punning should be avoided. What is the difference in the resulting code? https://godbolt.org/z/t9z_Sn

Comment: That's not pointer punning by the usual definition of the term.  The C standard explicitly permits examining the bytes of an object's representation via a pointer to a character type.

Comment: `detect_endianess` relies on undefined behaviour (you can't legally set one field in a union and then read the other field).

Comment: @Brendan please show me in the C standard this undefined behaviour

Comment: @Brendan, the standard offers via a union type that includes the object's type among its members as one of the allowed ways to access an object ([C2011, 6.5/7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7)).  This is one of the provisions of the strict aliasing rule, which is the only source of such access restrictions that I am aware of.  So yes, you may set one member of a union and read another, so long as you do it *via* the union.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do this in a platform-independent way, or do I need to use #ifdefs and have a separate piece of code for each endianness?

No, that doesn't even make sense. Anything that cares about a specific characteristic of a platform (e.g. endianness) can't be platform independent.

Example 1 (platform independent):

```
// Copy the 3 least significant bytes to dest[]

dest[0] = value & 0xFF; dest[1] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF; dest[2] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
```

Example 2 (platform independent):

```
// Copy the 3 most significant bytes to dest[]

dest[0] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF; dest[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF; dest[2] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

Example 3 (platform dependent):

```
// I want the least significant bytes on some platforms and the most significant bytes on other platforms

#ifdef PLATFORM_TYPE_A
    dest[0] = value & 0xFF; dest[1] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF; dest[2] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
#endif
#ifdef PLATFORM_TYPE_B
    dest[0] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF; dest[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF; dest[2] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
#endif
```

Note that it makes no real difference what the cause of the platform dependence is (if it's endianness or something else), as soon as you have a platform dependence you can't have platform independence.